# Can I group test methods and/or test classes in Python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, phpunit, python-unittest

Coming from PHPUnit, it was easy to group test classes or functions using the[`@group` annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group). That way I could run or exclude a very particular subset of tests, potentially across multiple files.

I'm wondering if python unittest has something similar. If that is the case how do I use it and run it from the CLI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to run a group of test functions by putting them all in a single class. Let's say you have 4 test functions in your unittest and you want to have two groups of 2 functions. You need to create a tests.py script with two classes, each of which having 2 functions:

```
from unittest import TestCase
class testClass1(TestCase):
   def testFunction1(self):
      #test something
   def testFunction2(self):
      #test something
class testClass2(TestCase):
   def testFunction3(self):
      #test something
   def testFunction4(self):
      #test something
```

Then to run your unittest only on class 1 from command line, you can run

```
python -m unittest tests.testClass1
```